# Need to join SQL table with multiple match, if value doesn't matches it should return a blank/NA value

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, left-join

I want to join below tables in such a way that that it should return matched value if not matching it should return a value as `"NA"`.
below are the table details

available tables:
[image: available tables]

desired output:
[image: desired output table]

Comment: So...what have you tried so far???

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not links, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained.

Comment: This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya  Please do not inline links inappropriately. See my comment above re using text whenever possible. Either replace a link to a table by code block formatted tabular text (which should simultaneously be code to create & initialize a table since the question should give a [mcve]) or, much better, comment to tell the poster to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use `Left Join` between the tables, to consider those rows also which do not exist in the `Process` table.
- You can use [`Ifnull()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function, to set the value `NA` if no matching row (thus `null` value) in the `Process` table.

Try the following (change table and column name(s) accordingly):

```
SELECT r.Ticket_id, 
       r.Status,
       r.Department, 
       r.Owner, 
       r.Process_id, 
       IFNULL(p.Proces_Name, 'NA')
FROM Resolution AS r 
LEFT JOIN Process AS p ON p.Process_id = r.Process_id
```

Comment: Hi Madhur, thanks for the response. If I want to display matches with only 3 process id (like with 34, 76 and 56), and rest as null. then how I will proceed?

Comment: @UttamSharma You can add this on Left join condition, eg: `LEFT JOIN Process AS p ON p.Process_id = r.Process_id AND r.Process_id IN (34,76,56)`

Comment: SELECT r.Ticket_id, 
       r.Status,
       r.Department, 
       r.Owner, 
       r.Process_id, 
       IFNULL(p.Proces_Name, 'NA')
FROM Resolution AS r 
LEFT JOIN Process AS p ON p.Process_id = r.Process_id AND r.Process_id IN (34,76,56)

Comment: this is my query, where I am getting details of not able to fetch NA details, if accessory a on a.id not equal to va.accessory_id. tried using IFNULL 
 
select tt.process_number,tt.product_code,tt.nearest_station,
concat(left(a.name,3),'-',right(left(a.name,9),3)) as accessory from task_tracking tt
left join line_haul_trip lht on lht.id = tt.journey_id
left join vns_accessory va on va.process_number = tt.process_number
left join accessory a on a.id = va.accessory_id
where a.is_active = 1 and va.is_active = 1 and tt.is_active = 1 and 
va.accessory_id IN (221,222,223, 224,)

Comment: @UttamSharma for the where conditions using the parameters of the "right side" tables in the left join, will restrict your data (filter it) and you will never get null (na) data. Instead of specifying those conditions in the `where` clause, you should specify them in the join `on` condition.

Comment: @UttamSharma use the following query instead:  `select tt.process_number,tt.product_code,tt.nearest_station, concat(left(a.name,3),'-',right(left(a.name,9),3)) as accessory from task_tracking tt left join line_haul_trip lht on lht.id = tt.journey_id left join vns_accessory va on va.process_number = tt.process_number and va.is_active = 1 and va.accessory_id IN (221,222,223,224) left join accessory a on a.id = va.accessory_id and a.is_active = 1 where tt.is_active = 1`

Comment: @UttamSharma Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If a value isn't found in a MySQL `LEFT JOIN`, the field is "filled" with `NULL`

The best practice, as I understand your question is IFNULL

```
SELECT
 r.*,
 IFNULL(process_name,'NA')
FROM
resolution r
LEFT JOIN processes p ON p.process_id = r.process_id
```

Comment: And why would `IFNULL()` be a *best practice* when there is an ISO/ANSI standard function that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.ticket_id,a.status,a.department,a.ownername,
case
when b.process_name is null then 'NA'
else b.process_name
end as proces_name
from resolution_tab a
left join process_tab b
on a.process_id=b.process_id
order by a.ticket_id;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.